# JS string parsing adding and removing values like jQuery does

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ultimately, I'm trying to recreate the string parsing behavior of the jQuery addClass and removeClass methods, only I want to do it on a string that I pass to a function. Unfortunately JS is not my strongest language especially when it comes to the string parsing functions that are available. Below is some sudo code in JS to show the method signatures that I want.

```
function addValue(str, value){
     // Add value to string if it does not all ready have it. Do not duplicate values
}  

function removeValue(str, value){
    // Remove value from string if it is applied
}
```

I have no idea how to do this in JS. Below is the code I would us if I was doing this in PHP.

```
function addValue(&$str, $newValue)
{
    $newValue = trim($newValue);
    $values = explode(' ', $str);
    if (!in_array($newValue, $values)) {
        $values[] = $newValue;
    }

    $str = implode(' ', $values);
}

function removeValue(&$str, $value)
{
    $values = explode(' ', $str);
    if($index = array_search($value, $values)){
        unset($values[$index]);
    }
    $str = implode(' ', $values);
}
```

I haven't test that PHP code but hopefully that's enough for someone to understand what I'm trying to do. My question is, what is the JS equivalent of the PHP code provided here?

---

**Solution**

I ended up going with Nouphal.M code because it did seem to be a little more x-browser friendly and it handled empty strings ('') well. Thank you everyone for helping out on this. My final code below is in the form of a jQuery function. I probably should have mentioned earlier that the string i was targeting was stored in $(elm).data() so i was able to get my desired behavior i.e. not having to return anything.

**EDIT** 
I refactored the functions so they live inside the String class. You need to reassign the value with this method like so str = str.addWord('something'); I kept my jQuery functions but i feel this method is a little more generic and might be a little more useful for the next dev that needs to do this.

```
String.prototype.addWord =
    function (value) {
        var str = this;

        var arr = str.split(" ");
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == value) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found == false) {
            str += " " + value;
        }
        return str;
    }

String.prototype.removeWord =
    function (value) {
        var str = this;
        var arr = str.split(" ");
        str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != value) {
                str += arr[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        return str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Please note that in the PHP code the $str param is passed by reference. I'd like to recreate this in JS so that I don't have to send back a return value.

Comment: Again JS isnt my strongest language but couldn't i attach a function to the string type that could handle this. Either via jQuery or some other mystical JS way? So it would be myString.addValue(value) and myString.removeValue()? im not 100% married to the (str, value) interface, i just dont want to have to do something like, myStr = addValue(myStr, value);

Comment: You can make all your strings inherit a method, but since strings are immutable, and JavaScript doesn't have pointers, you need to modify the string and return it, and have the caller replace the original. `myString = myString.addValue(value);`

Comment: @procrastinator Actually you can by extending `String.prototype`.

Comment: I know, but you still have to return the new value and override the old value with it, just like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117228/js-string-parsing-adding-and-removing-values-like-jquery-does#comment33553256_22117228.

Comment: @procrastinator: Your *"you can't"* comments didn't really explain that though. Maybe you were putting off the full explanation until later. ;-D

Comment: @cookiemonster Sorry for that :D Hard for me to explain some ideas since my english is not really good. Your explanation is pretty clear by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function addValue(str,value){
  var arr = str.split(" ");
    var found = false;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]==value){
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found == false ){
      str += " "+value;   
    }
    return str;
}
```

To remove value from string

```
function removeValue(str,value){
  var arr = str.split(" ");
    str = "";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]!=value){
            str += arr[i]+" ";
        }
    }
    str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);
    return str;
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CfCD6/)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this :

```
function addValue(str, newVal) {
    var values = str.match(/\S+/g) || [];
    if (values.indexOf(newVal) === -1) values.push(newVal);
    return values.join(' ');
}

function remValue(str, val) {
    var values = str.match(/\S+/g) || [],
        idx = values.indexOf(newVal);
    if (idx !== -1) values.splice(idx, 1);
    return values.join(' ');
}
```

For IE8- support, you could replace `values.indexOf(newVal)` with `jQuery.inArray(newVal, values)`. There is another workaround here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf.

A custom one :

```
function indexOf(array, value) {
    var i = -1, l = array.length;
    while (++i < l) {
        if (array[i] === value) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 though you can use `/\S+/g` To deal with various whitespace characters. Little safer that way. :-)

Comment: As far as cross browser goes, it seems like Nouphal.M solution might be a little safer, or am I wrong about that? Sorry, total client side noob here.

Comment: The only drawback is the use of `indexOf()` which is not supported by old browsers, but you can easily work around this problem, for that matter, I've provided a few solutions.

Comment: @SteveZurek Empty string support added ;) I had forgotten that `match()` returns `null` in case of failure.

Comment: These functions are going to end in a little framework I'm working on, and they are likely to be called many times. How would one test the efficiency of these functions to decide which one is optimal?